# matplotlib and tkinter interactive: How to select the defined Frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a problem using matplotlib in Tkinter.

Here is the plan:
*1. Define a `Button` and a `Frame` (Frame_0) using Tkinter.

2. By clicking the `Button` to plot the sin-function using `matplotlib`, which is shown in `Frame_0`*.

But I don't know how to do it.

I am just a beginner. But I just think the easist way to do it might be,  'selecting' the widget by using `get_tk_widget()`, is it possible? Or is there some other commands to do it?

Hope you understand my poor English and my beginners question. Here is the code.
Thank you all.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def command_0():
    f = Figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2 * pi * t)
    a.plot(t, s)

    dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    dataPlot.show()
    dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    root.mainloop()


def Main():
    global root

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Program")
    root['background']='gray'

    w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d" %(w, h))
    root.state("zoomed")

    global Frame_0
    Frame_0 = Frame(root)
    Frame_0.place(height=600, width=800, x=10, y=10)


    Frame_1 = Frame(root)
    Frame_1.place(width=120, height=80, x=1000, y=20)
    Button_1 = Button(Frame_1, text = "Click", width = 120, height=80, bg='green', command = command_0)
    Button_1.place(x=1000, y=20)
    Button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    Button_1.pack()


    root.mainloop()
    return
Main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wont to show it in `frame_0`, i don't know why you are setting the `master=root`. Simply change:

```
dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
```

to:

```
dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=Frame_0)
```

Also you don't need that `root.mainloop()` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much!